# roation on trigger oculus go c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, coroutine, oculus

I'm looking to have a game object rotate when the trigger on the oculus go is pressed but only then, I have the following code. Unfortunately this continuously roates even when I take my finger off the trigger,

```
public GameObject dummyrotate;
private bool rotate = false;
float rotationAmount = .3f;
float delaySpeed = .1f;


public void rotateAntiClockwise()

{
    StartCoroutine(SlowSpin2());
}

public IEnumerator SlowSpin2()

{
    float count = 0;
    while (count <= 90)

    {
        dummyrotate.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,-rotationAmount,0));
        count += rotationAmount;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delaySpeed);
    }
}
```

many thanks
Jono

Comment: When does this rotateAntiClockwise gets called? What is the value of rotationAmount?

Comment: I've just updated the code. 'rotateAntiClockwise' gets called by a  'Pointer down'  event trigger on a game object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want it to rotate while the trigger is being held, just don't use a coroutine for that. Coroutines will run until they are completely done, so instead try something like this:

```
public GameObject dummyrotate;
private bool rotate = false;
float rotationAmount = .3f;
float delaySpeed = .1f;


void Update()
{
    SlowSpin2();
}

public void SlowSpin2()

{
    if (rotate == true) {
        dummyrotate.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,-rotationAmount,0));
        count += rotationAmount;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, sorry for being slow but how do you control the bool rotate being false or true through the  event trigger though?

Comment: Find which input you need on [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/OculusControllers.html) site, then in Unity, go to Project Settings > Input, and put in which ever input you need, then add in this to your script: `bool rotate = Input.GetButton("someInputName")`, where the string is the same as what you called it in the Input Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Well the problem is once you trigger rotation it will take 30 second to complete your `coroutine` because of your while loop. And also when you trigger it again you start another `coroutine` this will go on forever like this. I am assuming `rotateAntiClockwise` method is called every time your trigger is pressed.

I am also assuming you want to rotate the object 90 degree in y axis you can achieve it like this:

```
 bool isRunning = false;
 //Make sure this variable is true when triggered and false when not
 bool isTrigger = false;
 float rotationAmount = 0.3f;
 public IEnumerator SlowSpin2()
 {
    isRunning = true;
    //This will rotate the object continuously until isTriggered is false
    while (isTriggered)
    {
        Debug.Log("Rotating");
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -rotationAmount, 0));            
        yield return null;

    }
    Debug.Log(Time.time);
    isRunning = false;
 }
```

This script will rotate your object from 0 to 90 slowly in 2 seconds.

Then you have to modify your `rotateAntiClockwise` like this so you wont start another coroutine while this one is already running.

```
public void rotateAntiClockwise()
{
     if(!isRunning)
         StartCoroutine(SlowSpin2());
}
```

Comment: thank you that does work, what I ultimately need though is for the object to continuously rotate for as long as pointer down is triggered, the moment it is not for it stop rotating.

Comment: Ah okay i understand. I updated my code this way it will rotate continuously until it is not triggered.